ROS How do I make the local planner as straight as possible
I am currently using ROS Melodic and the move_base package for navigation. I am utilizing the A* global planner and DWA local planner and would like the vehicle to follow a path passing through specific waypoints. These waypoints are aligned in a straight line, and since there are no obstacles, the A* global planner generates a global path that is almost perfectly straight. However, due to the characteristics of the local planner and variables such as the costmap values, the local planner often creates a slightly winding local path rather than following the straight global path generated by A*.
My question is: How can I ensure that the local path aligns as closely as possible to the straight global path? I would like to continue using the DWA planner in case obstacles appear, but I also want the path to be as straight as possible.
Should I adjust the move_base parameters, or are there other methods I should consider? I would greatly appreciate your advice.
Thank you in advance.

From dwa_local_planner documentation page, some trajectory parameters on DWA allow you to modify this behavior:
:
~<name>/path_distance_bias
~<name>/goal_distance_bias

Try to tune those parameters first. If it is not to your liking, you could try to use the TEB local planner, as the other answer said.

you could try to use TEB instead of DWA to get straighter trajectory. By default TEB will generate straight line if there are no obstacles. I will then bend the trajectory a bit when obstacle appears.
